# Why does OSX fail on parsing the extras_require section of my setup.py file?

Tags: python, macos, travis-ci, setup.py

In my `setup.py` file, I have the following:

```
setup(
    ...
    extras_require={
        ':python_version<="2.7"': [
            'pydot>1.0',
            ],
        ':python_version>="3.5"': [
            'pydot3k',
            ],
    ...
)
```

This works fine on Linux (on Travis CI) and Windows (on AppVeyor) but fails on OSX (also on Travis) with the error message:

> error in mypackage setup command: Invalid environment marker: python_version<="2.7"

What is the reason for this failure, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Do you have up-to-date pip and setuptools?

Comment: In my `.travis.yml` I have `- pip install --upgrade pip`. Should I also have `- pip install --upgrade setuptools`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `- pip install --upgrade setuptools` to my `.travis.yml` file.